# How do I change the order of comma and ending double-quote after the title?

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

An example of a BiBTeX reference of mine

```
@ARTICLE{58,
  author = {{Craig M. Pratt and Terry Eaton and Marilyn Francis and Antonio Pacifico}},
  title = {{Ambulatory  Electrocardiographic Recordings: The Holter Monitor}},
  journal = {{1988 Year Book Medical Publishers Inc.}},
  year = {1988},
  owner = {larselgaardmikkelsen},
  quality = {1},
  review = {hvad er en holter monitor},
  timestamp = {2013.05.06}
}
```

Output:

> Craig M. Pratt and M.D.n Terry Eaton and R.N. and Marilyn Francis R.N.
>   and Antonio Pacifico, M.D., “Ambulatory Electrocardiographic
>   Recordings: The Holter Monitor,” 1988 Year Book Medical Publishers
>   Inc., 1988.

How do I move the comma at the end of the title, so that it is outside the title? I have `"title,"` and I want `"title",`.
Added the following as a minimal example
This is my master.tex (shortened version)

```
\input{preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}% Page number in roman style
\input{frontpage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumé}
\input{resume}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname}
\input{abstract}
\input{preface}
\input{tableofcontent}
\mainmatter
\input{introduction}
.
.
\input{conclusion.tex}
\appendixpage
\appendix
\input{appendix.tex}
\backmatter
\input{akronym.tex}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\begingroup
\raggedright
\bibliography{references/speciale}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I am using Memoir.
And this is from my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input encoding - Depending on editor
\usepackage{lmodern} % Modern LaTeX font
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language package
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Hyphenation
\usepackage{fix-cm} % Fix for cm
\usepackage{graphicx} % To handle pictures
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} % Graphical tool
\usepackage{mathtools} % To use \eqref
\usepackage{url} % Use of urls in the text
\usepackage{varioref} % Smarter references
\usepackage{calc}% Auto calculate
\usepackage{lipsum} % Debugging text
\usepackage{sansmath,subfig} % Gives a warning because subfig loads caption
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

Hope this is better - if not please let me know.

Comment: you're not telling us what tools you're using to produce your bibliography: what engine, what style files, etc. Could you provide a [minimal working example?](http://goo.gl/5XLQU) Otherwise noone will be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: A separate comment: The bibliographic entry doesn't seem to be well suited for the `@article` entry type; e.g., there's no volume number, no issue number, no page(s). It may be better suited for the `@inbook` entry type, where you'd replace "journal" with "booktitle". Furthermore, you should really remove one set of curly braces around the contents of the `author` field, so that BibTeX can format them in conformance with whatever `\bibliographystyle` that you may have chosen.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is hardcoded in your bibliography style `ieeetr`. The relevant function is

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { "``" title "t" change.case$ * ",''" * }
  if$
}
```

If you change that into

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { "``" title "t" change.case$ * "''," * }  %% moved comma out
  if$
}
```

you get the desired output. But please make a copy of [`ieeetr.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/ieeetr.bst) for such edits, and call it, say, `myieeetr.bst`.

Of course, there is always the option to use a different bibliography style.

Comment: I don't seem to have a ieeetr.bst file - i have my tex files and a folder with a bib file. I using a Mac computer, and the program TexPad.

Comment: @jens In your code you are using `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`, so the `ieeetr.bst` has to be somewhere. I have mine in the TEXMF tree under `bibtex/bst/base/ieeetr.bst`